# Compressing a BufferedImage without writing to disk

Tags: java, image, compression, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I'd like to compress a `BufferedImage` without writing anything to the disk as the images represent frames from a video feed so writing to disk would obviously be too slow.

I looked at `ImageIO.write(image, "png", OutputStream)` but I can't think of what `OutputStream` to use to prevent writing the resulting compressed image to disk.

Comment: I suggest using ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", ByteArrayOutputStream) can be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) to write bytes to a byte array:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "png", out);
byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
```

After you have done the above, `bytes` will then hold the data that the image contains.

**Notice:** a ByteArrayOutputStream is a special input kind of `OutputStream`, you are not required to close it, but it never hurts if you still do it.